# How to sync a dynamic ImportRange data with static data in one google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, synchronization, importrange

I have 3 spreadsheets where 1 is a master sheet (to which everything is imported and everything is exported from).
**In the 1st spreadsheet** a person fills in **A:M** which is imported to the Master spreadsheet, then the **2nd spreadsheet imports A:M** range from the Master spreadsheet and the person in the 2nd spreadsheet adds additional data to **N:P** and Master spreadsheet also imports this to the correct row.

BUT the **2nd spreadsheet keeps desynchronizing** because if the person in the 1st spreadsheet adds data then **A:M data shifts down but the N:P data doesn't**

**Any** way of keep the two synched?

Comment: It's not clear how this questions involves [tag:google-apps-script]. Are you looking  solution that involves its use? Have you already done a effort to find a solution as required on [ask]?

Comment: If there is a way of doing this via script then I am open to it (and that tag was recommended by stackoverflow when I opened the topic)